# MySQL Unknown InnoDB Options on Command Line

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to set some innodb settings when starting mysql on the command line:

```
mysql -p*password* --skip-innodb_doublewrite

mysql -p*password* --innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
```

Which appear to be possible from the [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html):

> Command-Line Format  `--innodb-doublewrite` ... This variable can be turned off with `--skip-innodb_doublewrite`
>
> Command-Line Format  `--innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit[=#]`

However, when executing I get:

```
mysql: unknown option '--skip-innodb_doublewrite'

mysql: unknown variable 'innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0'
```

What's going on? Have I completely missinterpreted the docs?

I'm using MySQL 5.5.45

Comment: Those are options for `mysqld` startup, not `mysql`.

Comment: @Barmar Well, that would explain it! Put that in an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are server options, not client options, so they need to be specified on the `mysqld` command line. However, as the documentation says:

> Many system variables can be changed at runtime (see [Section 6.1.6.2, “Dynamic System Variables”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/dynamic-system-variables.html)).

If you go to that page, the first line says:

> Many server system variables are dynamic and can be set at runtime using `SET GLOBAL` or `SET SESSION`.

There's a table that lists all the dynamic variables. `innodb_doublewrite` is not one of them, so it can only be specified at server startup (either with a command-line argument or in the configuration file). But `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit` is listed as a global variable, so you can do:

```
mysql -u root -p"password" -e "set global innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0"
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is receiving the message `unknown variable 'innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0'` trying to set this configuration in a my.ini or mysql.cnf file, the line `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0` must be written under `[mysqld]` section.